# Adjusting Stylesheet Output Format

Tags: stylesheet

[image]I'm using one of *Mathematica*'s built-in stylesheets, "Standard Report". When I enter an expression into an input cell and evaluate it, the input is shown with a white background, while the output has a grey background.

However, when I generate a plot, the numbers on the axes have white boxes around them, which looks stupid next to the grey background.

How would I get rid of these white boxes?

Thanks!

Comment: I cannot reproduce it. Mma version, OS, code, and plot snapshot are needed t o address your question.

Comment: Can't reproduce it either (Win7-64, MMA 8.04)

Comment: Problem not reproduced on my setup -- _Mathematica_ v.8.0.4 on running on Mac OS X 10.6.8

Comment: I posted a screenshot

Comment: I can't reproduce this (same setup as m_goldberg). Just so we're clear you are using StandardReport and not making *any* private style modifications? What it looks like is that you have set `Background->White` for `TraditionalForm`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that TraditionalForm has its background set to white.

```
Cell[StyleData["TraditionalForm"],
 Background->None]
```

should fix this.

Comment: That did it. Thanks!